# Leaflet unproject from EPSG:25831 doesn't work

Tags: leaflet, proj4js

In a leaflet map that uses EPSG 25831 to get WMS request, it works fine to call to "project" function to get UTM coordinates of one coordinates pair that I got from the map in WGS84, but inverse function to "unproject" a pair of coordinates in UTM in order to get this equivalent in WGS84 doesn't work.

The console message is "unproject  is not a function"

The example code:

```
var crs = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:25831',
'+proj=utm +zone=31 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs',
{
    resolutions: [2000, 1100, 550, 275, 100, 50, 25, 10, 5, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.25]//,
    //origin: [0, 0]
}),
map = new L.Map('map', {
    crs: crs,
    continuousWorld: true
});


L.tileLayer.wms("http://server/service?", {
layers: 'topographic',
format: 'image/png',
transparent: true,
continuousWorld: true
}).addTo(map);

map.setView([41.3, 1], 6);

// UTM to 4326
var point = L.point(4651000,400000);
var newPoint = crs.unproject(point);
console.info(newPoint);
```

In the other hand, "project" function, works fine:

```
var testPoint = new L.latLng(42.12, 1);
var geo_point = crs.project(testPoint);
console.info(geo_point);
```

Versions used are, Leaflet: 0.7.7, proj4leaflet: 0.7.2, proj4: I don't know, it was at the Proj4Leaflet-0.7.2.zip from: github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet/releases

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you please specify which versions of Leaflet, proj4 and proj4leaflet you're using?

Comment: Does it work with `L.point(400000,4651000)`?

Comment: http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/etrs89-utm-zone-31n/ says the valid projected bounds are (238379.2278, 4265559.3497, 761620.7722, 6914547.3835), which your point is not in.

Comment: Versions used are, Leaflet: 0.7.7, proj4leaflet: 0.7.2, proj4: I don't know, it was at the Proj4Leaflet-0.7.2.zip from: https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet/releases

Comment: It doesn't work using L.point(400000,4651000), the same error

Comment: Using L.point(400000,4651000) coord are inside bounds, but it doesn't work. In my question I've changed order because I supose it was the correct order, but the error is not in this way

Comment: Finnally a collegue has found the solution. project and unproject functions are inside a L.Proj.Projection object, so to call unproject, the right way is:
    'crs.projection.unproject(point);'

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Finnally a collegue has found the solution. "project" and "unproject" functions are inside a L.Proj.Projection object, so to call unproject, the right way is: `crs.projection.unproject(point);`